# How to send one value and display another value in text box using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Is it possible to display one value and send another value at the same time in Input text field?

For example `2` is the current value shown in `<input>` box when i `onchange` the `<select>` box.

Now I need to send the value `3` for that `<input>` box but need to display `2`.

**Example:**

```
<input type="text" value="2" name="test1">
```

should display `2` in the page and need to pass `3` to next page.

If I `echo $_POST["test1"]` it should print `3`.

Comment: "Now I need to send the value 3 for that input text box but need to display 3." Do you mean you need to display 2?

Comment: your question is not very clear.  Can you post some code?  Do you have a select dropdown and a textbox?

Comment: @yasser , can you please check once again my question ?

Comment: @Munzilla,please check my question once

Answer (score 1):

try this (*if i understood your question correctly*):

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var val = this.value;
   $('input.select').val(val);
})
```

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/hp8cr/

**ON QUESTION UPDATE**

Why not on the PHP side just add one to the post:

```
echo ($_POST["test1"] + 1);
```

Comment: can you please check once again my question ?

Comment: @Dinesh, so why not on the php side just add one to the number? im not sure what the issue is

Comment: Thanks neal,actually as for example ,i gave 2, we can use some character/words.At this point,how can we do

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery and ajax post, you can achieve this.

```
$.post("myscript.php",
   { test2: $('#test2').val(val),      // Submit normally
     test1: '3'                        // Change the value
   },
   function(data){
      // Handle response here
   });

)
```